# Primefaces dataTable filter options attribute to show all records

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.1.In my dataTable I used facet filter  drop down options used it will work in only once again choose another dropdown value it not working it show null pointer exception in logger. So I user **filteroptions** attribute in this option to add value in selectItem now change dropdown to work fine but again need All records I get it?

```
 <p:column  id="statusHeadingColumn" headerText="status
filterBy="#{user.status}"  filterMatchMode="exact" filterOptions="#{user.statusNameSelectItem}">
<h:outputText id="statusColumn" value="#{user.status}"/>
</p:column>
```

Filter options attribute again to show how to get all records?

Answer (score 2):

When constructing SelectItem[] of statusNameSelectItem at filterOptions="#{user.statusNameSelectItem}" setting

```
statusNameSelectItem[0] = new SelectItem("", "All");
```

works for me. So that when "All" selected in dropdown, all records shown

Comment: Where do you apply this? A little more context would help a lot!

Comment: I thought it was convenient enough for someone who able to ask such a question. Used same variable name in asker's code. Anyway, edited my answer. Thank you